# What is the contribution of weapons industry lobbying in current enmities and wars?

Tags: military, lobbying

The Yemeni war has been very profitable for the weapons industry, costing Saudi Arabia 120 billion dollars. Currently the global military GDP is 1.5 trillion dollars, 1.75% of the world economy. It spends 300 million on official lobbying.

Can that 300 million spent yearly on politicians by military companies have a major negative effect on foreign policy and world peace?

In many regions, the military owns the government or is the dependable right-hand-man of the government.

Can we find evidence that they influence foreign policy and the threat levels of military announcements that are made by governments to each other? Even for the EU and US?

Comment: If evidence for that would be publicly available there probably would be outcry. It will be very difficult to quantify any such effect. Politicians around the world seem often eager to start a war. The weapons industry may not need much to do to persuade countries to buy weapons.

Comment: It's kept firmly in the blind spot of society, perhaps investigative journalists have found leads? There is suspicion about the influence of lobbying for example 320.000 spent by AQMI strategy corp. for just one armament contract. Even the official lobbying is discreet so it's a challenge to study it's $1.5 trillion influences and effects. https://left.eu/issues/publications/rhetoric-and-reality-of-disinformation-in-the-european-union/

Comment: Good investigative journalists are rare and often receive death threats if they study interference which hides from the US Foreign Agents Act (FARA)... https://www.euractiv.com/section/politics/short_news/prominent-bulgarian-investigative-journalist-threatened-with-assassination/ There's are about $7 billion of declared international influence money spent yearly including 2-3 billion from military companies... I want to understand military lobbying, grafting and influence, specifically.

Comment: Bribes to obtain foreign armament contracts are often in the 1-100 million range. Funnily enough the policing is not incentivised by democracy, journalism and politicians. It's policed by other military companies who lose out while trying to secure armament spending. https://www.google.com/search?q=grafting+%22military+contract%22&sxsrf=APq-WBsrsfmQcnj4p3HDgHyCQ76cI_t22A:1646876714588&ei=KlgpYvKcI4KblwTzpar4Aw&start=10&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjy2b7stbr2AhWCzYUKHfOSCj8Q8NMDegQIARBK&biw=1272&bih=645&dpr=1.88

Comment: Sure, companies will lobby against each other, but that doesn't have to have an impact on wars. It might just mean that you end up with different weapons.

Comment: Military lobbyists vie for higher military spending, not just different. One way they achieve higher weapons spending is that they recommend to politicians to establish defense committees, research bodies and defense funds. For example, a defense fund was recently created with a budget of 80 billion in a government which was previously only an free trade organization, and it's mission closely mirrors documents submitted by corporations. That's one way it can work. Another way is direct lobbying for war by research groups: Wars can occur 5 years after the research groups start lobbying for it.

Comment: Worldwide military spending in the last 20 years was relatively low compared to the times before (more like 2.5% of GDP, when it was like 4% of GDP during Cold War times). Surely there are also examples of countries that spend less on weapons now than they used to. Even without lobbying, countries would probably still buy weapons. I don't want to say what you're saying is wrong and it's definitely an interesting question, just that it's very difficult next to impossible to give any quantitative answer.

Comment: There is the [Stockholm peace institute](https://sipri.org/) a very renowned institution. They could know more. Maybe write them and ask your question there. If you get an answer you can post a summary here for example.